# Add tika bridge to new defined field in FieldBridge

Tags: hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I have entity witch points to binary data by numeric identifier (`binId`). Utility class can provide binary stream form given ID. My target is to index this binary stream - usually a file.

The concept is, to create bridge for binary data identifier field. Inside bridge I'll call utility class, gets stream and create new Field with given stream. Then I'd like this stream to be indexed/analyzed by [Tika bridge](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4034).

I use [FieldBridge](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#example-field-bridge) but without LuceneOptions. Additionally I can not annotate entity class, so I use [Programmatic API](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/search/4.2/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e4904).

So far it looks like:

```
public class SearchMappingFactory {
    @Factory
    public SearchMapping getSearchMapping(){
        SearchMapping mapping = new SearchMapping();
        mapping.entity(Attachment.class)
            .indexed()
            .property("id", ElementType.FIELD)
            .documentId()
            .property("name", ElementType.FIELD)
            .field()
            .property("description", ElementType.FIELD)
            .field()
            .property("binId", ElementType.FIELD)
            .field()
            .name("attachmentFile")
            .bridge(AttachmentContentSearchBridge.class)
            .property("content", ElementType.FIELD)  // this is my try to define additional bridge
            .field()
            .bridge(TikaBridge.class)
        ;
        return mapping;
    };
}
```

and my bridge:

```
public class AttachmentContentSearchBridge implements FieldBridge {

    @Override
    public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
        Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(MyBinUtil.getStreamForId((Integer)value));
        Field field = new Field("content",reader);
//i'd like to add tika bridge here, but i cant
        document.add(field);
    }
}
```

Lets start with bridge. It's quite simple, the only problem is, that I can not define bridge to new created field `content` - that is the major problem I get.

I tried to solve it by adding `content` field to my mapping, where I can define bridge. The definition is accepted and my application starts and works, but index for `content` has no keywords :(

Please give my any advice how to define TikeBridge for field created within FieldBridge.

Thank for you time reading it and hope your help.

Comment: Does your entity have a 'content' property? You cannot just add this property to the programmatic API if it is not backed by a real property in the entity. Maybe you could post the code for Attachment.

Comment: @Hardy No, my entity has not content property. I created it in bridge only for search purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you get the stream data via an id and a custom util class, you cannot use the @TikaBridge annotation. As the documentation of the annotation suggests it only works for binary data fields or String/URL fields. In the latter case the String/URL are used to load the binary data.

In your case you just have to re-implement what happens in [*org.hibernate.search.bridge.builtin.TikaBridge*](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-search/blob/master/engine/src/main/java/org/hibernate/search/bridge/builtin/TikaBridge.java).

The interesting parts are:

```
public void set(String name, Object value, Document document, LuceneOptions luceneOptions) {
    if ( value == null ) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException( "null cannot be passed to Tika bridge" );
    }
    InputStream in = null;
    try {
        in = getInputStreamForData( value );

        Metadata metadata = metadataProcessor.prepareMetadata();
        ParseContext parseContext = parseContextProvider.getParseContext( name, value );

        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        WriteOutContentHandler contentHandler = new WriteOutContentHandler( writer );

        Parser parser = new AutoDetectParser();
        parser.parse( in, contentHandler, metadata, parseContext );
        luceneOptions.addFieldToDocument( name, writer.toString(), document );

        // allow for optional indexing of metadata by the user
        metadataProcessor.set( name, value, document, luceneOptions, metadata );
    }
    catch ( Exception e ) {
        throw propagate( e );
    }
    finally {
        closeQuietly( in );
    }
}
```

You need an input stream of your data, then you create a tika parser and pass it the stream together with an output StringWriter to which Tika can write the data. In the end you need to add the extracted data as new field using LuceneOptions.

Comment: I used stream, because for me it is easier to use it instead of byte[]. This is not an issue for me to create field with type byte[], witch is supported by TikaBridge. The major question form me is, how to apply bridge for fields created inside custom field/class bridge?

Comment: You can not. @TikaBridge and the underlying TikaBridge implementation are used for fields on the actual entity. You cannot use it from inside a custom bridge. In this case you have to write the actual code yourself. See above.